# Cannondale warranty

Tags: cannondale

My Cannondale Ultegra DI2 Road Bike is 6 months old,I did not use it over winter so have ridden some 300 miles on it. Today chain broke, causing rear mech hanger to break, which damaged carbon stay. What chance do i have claiming on Cannondale warranty?

Thanks Joe

Comment: Call Cannondale and ask.

Comment: Was this the original chain, installed by factory or shop?

Comment: Hi Daniel this is the original chain installed by factory or cycle store.co.uk. Cannondale rec taking to approved shop doing so tomorrow.

Comment: Exact same thing happened to my friend (on a Cannondale after only 6 months - more distance than you) and he got a whole new frame without any fee.  Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there’s no point asking us to speculate about what Cannondale would say, instead of just asking Cannondale.

Comment: Hi I am new to this forum and as is obvious i wanted people to share their knowledge and experiences as i was dismayed at the prospect of a  £3000 bike potentially being unusable.I took bike to authorised dealer today and was told the decision lies with Cannondale who look at report from dealer. Dealer said it was very unlikely that warranty would cover damage caused by chain link which failed. Same response from cyclestore who i purchased bike from they E-mailed me offering to replace rear mech hanger. Puzzled by comment by David,i now realise now how on topic this matter of warranties  is!!!

Comment: @joel its also strong regional-bias too.  Some areas like EU have 2 year minimums.   You may have to consult your local Citizens Advice Bureau for a local opinion.  It may progress to a Small Claims Tribunal or similar, which is like a petty-court for small amounts.  Do keep ALL your documentation and receipts and make a written diary of who you spoke to, on what date, and what they said exactly.

Comment: Thanks Criggie i will pursue this matter through legal avenue if it does not get sorted.

Answer (score 4):

The only answer to this is to go to the store where you bought the bike and ask.

IMHO: seems derailleur hanger failing to protect the chain stay seems like a possible cause for a warranty claim.

Comment: Chain cleaned and maintained regularly so I feel as all parts are warranted it should be covered.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess probably not covered; things that happen in the course of riding (e.g. the chain breaking) aren't generally causes for warranty claims. Of course, warranty stuff does depend on country and everything else.

I would take the bike to a Cannondale authorized shop for them to verify this (preferred; they can also arrange repairs to the bike if necessary/required/possible), and/or call Cannondale.

Comment: Thanks am taking to shop 300 miles for a chain? I would normally change when stretched or around 1500 miles.